# getting the first proc arriving at some point, asynchronously

Tags: mpi

My program start with each process doing some work, and in the end one should gather the result and compute the final result. For now, everybody send the data to the proc 0, and it is the one that does the final computational task. I would like to find a to do this on the first process that finishes its local task.

Is there a trick on finding out this proc and tell to all the other procs asynchronously? I was thinking of using asynchronous collective operation but can't find a way to do it.

Thanks, 
Stole

Comment: If your program is nicely load-balanced it doesn't matter which process is first to finish its local task.  If your program is not nicely load-balanced, well, that's something a lot of programmers work hard to put right.  You may be able to implement your design, perhaps using the MPI-3 *nonblocking collectives* such as `MPI_Iallreduce`, but any implementation will impose an overhead on all processes.  Again, communication overhead is something many programmers work hard to minimise.  Are you sure you wouldn't be better off fixing the load balance ?

Comment: Your question implies that in order to do the final computational task, you do not need the results of all the tasks, but the result of a single task is enough. Is this really what you have in mind ?

Comment: the result of a single task is enough, I need all the data. But I would like to perform the final task (that receives data from all the processes) on the process that finishes first its local task. I would like to do this on the first one, because it needs to do some initialization computations. This way I reduce the overall execution time.

Comment: you can use one sided operations and atomically increment a global counter previously initialized to zero. That will tell you if a given task is the first to finish its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gilles said, you can use a one sided operation ([useful docs](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-onesided.html)) to set a variable which will contain the rank of process which have finished first. You set the variable to -1, when a process have finished, it read that variable using one sided (first think about blocking the access of other processes to avoid races) if it is -1, the process set this variable to his rank and become the "master" if it is a number >=0 then the process become a slave (of that number).

(As gilles noted: With version >3.0 one can use MPI_Compare_and_swap to perform the Get and Put by once (which is probably faster that a Get followed by a Put))

This method works fine only if you have a real difference of execution time between processes and a small number of processes. So one should be careful when losing time on implementing such solution. If you have large load imbalance (and cant redesign the parallelization to increase load ballancing) that will make the job! 
Then if you targeting >10 processes, it is better to first group all processes on a nested subgroups grid. Then perform the trick at each level of groups (that avoid having 100k processes trying to read the same variable and wasting huge time!)

Here is a simple code which does it...

```
  #include <mpi.h>
  #include <thread>
  #include <chrono>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <time.h>


  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

      MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

      int rank;
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

      srand (time(NULL)+rank);
      int wt = rand() % 5 + 1;
      cout <<"rank: "<< rank<< " sleep: "<< wt<<endl;



      //here is the magic...

      int * flag;
      MPI_Win window;
      int master;
      int compare = -1;
      MPI_Win_allocate(sizeof(int), sizeof(int),MPI_INFO_NULL,
                       MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &window );


      *flag = -1;
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(wt));


      MPI_Win_lock (MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, 0, 0, window);
      MPI_Compare_and_swap(&rank, &compare, &master, MPI_INT, 0,0, window);
      MPI_Win_unlock (0, window);


      if(master == -1)
      {
        cout<< "rank: "<<rank<<". I am the master"<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout<< "rank: "<<rank<<". I am the slave of "<<master<<endl;
      }


      MPI_Win_free( &window );
      MPI_Finalize();
  }
```

Outputs:

```
mpirun --oversubscribe  -np 4 ./test
rank: 2 sleep: 4
rank: 3 sleep: 1
rank: 0 sleep: 5
rank: 1 sleep: 2
rank: 3. I am the master
rank: 1. I am the slave of 3
rank: 2. I am the slave of 3
rank: 0. I am the slave of 3
mpirun --oversubscribe  -np 4 ./test
rank: 0 sleep: 2
rank: 1 sleep: 4
rank: 2 sleep: 1
rank: 3 sleep: 3
rank: 2. I am the master
rank: 0. I am the slave of 2
rank: 3. I am the slave of 2
rank: 1. I am the slave of 2
```

Comment: note you can replace `MPI_Get(...); if (...) MPI_Put(...)` with a single `MPI_Fetch_and_op()`

Comment: I dont see how.. Which reduce operation to use? The point is that you do the put only if the flag store -1. And the OP parameter cannot be a lambda (would be so great!). If you can modify my code to make it work with a MPI_Fetch_and_op(), i am interested ;-). the goal is not only to know if the process is first, but to let all process to know which one is first...

Comment: `MPI_SUM` with `1` in `origin_addr`. if `result_addr` is `-1`, then we are first. Or use `MPI_Compare_and_swap()` if other tasks need to know who is the first.

Comment: Thanks didnt know MPI_Compare_and_swap... lol should read changes of version 3... I test it now :-)